# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Why do I have this error in interactive visual studio?

My Python version is 3.10.6

My Ipython is 8.14.0

My system is Ubuntu 22

I have folders as follows:

```
code-> 
-> test
  test.ipynb
-> src 
   util.py
```

Then inside test/test.ipynb, I have "

```
from src.util import read_file
```

So I am running test.ipynb and I get that error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' - Jupyter Notebook
```

Comment: You need to provide more information, such as src is your own folder or a module you installed?   Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: src is a common folder in which we define some py files inside it.

Comment: So please show your file structure.   **Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**

Comment: I have seen that one.

Comment: This the structure: I have code-> test , src then inisde src i have util.py from util.py I want to read a class. so inside test/test.ipynb, I have "from src.util import read_file "    so I am running test.ipynb and I get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Add the following at the top of your code

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
```

[image]

##### You can check `PYTHONPATH` in current jupyte kernel with following code.

```
import os
print(os.environ.get("PYTHONPATH"))
```

[image]